# Issue with Eclipse and Play!2 plugins

Tags: eclipse, playframework

I'm trying to use the Mailer plugin with my Play project and I've ran into a little trouble. The project compiles well and I can access the website on my localhost, yet eclipse shows errors:

```
def sendEmail = Action {
    import play.api.Play.current
    import com.typesafe.plugin._
    val mail = use[MailerPlugin].email
    mail.setSubject("mailer")
    mail.addRecipient("Peter Hausel Junior <noreply@email.com>","example@foo.com")
    mail.addFrom("Peter Hausel <noreply@email.com>")
    //sends html
    mail.sendHtml("<html>html</html>" )
    //sends text/text
    mail.send( "text" )
    //sends both text and html
    mail.send( "text", "<html>html</html>")

     Ok(views.html.indexLoggedout())
  }
```

The error refers to line 2: plugin is not a member of com.typesafe

Here is Build.scala

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.0.4"
)
```

And play.plugins

```
1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
```

As I said, the project compiles ok when using `play compile`, it's just Eclipse that shows errors. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try eclipsify command?

Comment: Are you using Scala IDE under Eclipse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I've found to be a solution. Do:

```
play clean
play compile
play eclipsify
```

And then wait for Eclipse to rebuild the workspace. This should solve any plugin dependencies issues.